# Python: Generalised try-except wrapper for standalone and for loop continue

Tags: python, for-loop, exception

Apologies if this question has been asked before, but I wasn't able to find a similar question and hoped SO would recommend me one as I typed.

Scenario: Manually created folders with subfolder and files. At each level of folders I want to perform a particular function. Rather than raise an exception each time an error encountered, I'd like to print them out and continue the loop so I have a complete list of errors at the end.

Here is a MWE using simplified functions of what my code looks like:

```
import os, stat

def folder_info(folder):
    if len(folder) > 20:
        raise Exception('Folder {} name too long'.format(folder))
    print(folder)
    subfolders = os.listdir(folder)
    return len(folder), subfolders

raise_error = False

folders = [f for f in os.listdir() if os.path.isdir(f)]

for folder in folders:
    try: 
        length, subfolders = folder_info(folder)
    except Exception as error:
        if raise_error: raise
        print('Error: {}'.format(error))
        continue

    for subfolder in subfolders:
        subfolder = os.path.join(folder, subfolder)
        try: 
            length, subfolders = folder_info(subfolder)
        except Exception as error:
            if raise_error: raise
            print('Error: {}'.format(error))
            continue
```

Ideally I'd like something where I don't have to type out a `try` and `except` statement for each nested loop. What I'm hoping for:

```
for folder in folders:
    arg1, arg2 = exceptionwrapper(myfunction1(folder), raise_error)

    for subfolder in arg2:
    subfolder = os.path.join(folder, subfolder)
    arg1, arg2, arg3 = exceptionwrapper(myfunction2(subfolder), raise_error)

        for subsubfolder in arg3:
        arg1, arg2 = exceptionwrapper(myfunction3(subsubfolders), raise_error)
```

I've tried following solutions with decorator functions but I wasn't able to pass in `continue` or figure out where it should go. This is my best attempt and I have a syntax error trying to pass in `continue`:

```
def exceptionwrapper(function, raise_error, after_error: function = continue):
    def decorator(func):
        def new_func(*args, **kwargs):
            try:
                return func(*args, **kwargs)
            except Exception as error:
                if raise_error: raise
                print('Error: {}'.format(error))
                return after_error
            return new_func
        return decorator
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Your entire code can be written in few lines in a `Pythonic` way, if you could have used [os.walk](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/os.html#os.walk).

```
import os
for root, folders, files in os.walk(os.getcwd()):
    for folder in folders:
        print('dir is: ', folder)
        try:
            if len(folder) > 20:
                raise Exception('Folder {} name too long'.format(folder))
        except Exception as error_message:
            print('Error in folder: {} due to: {}'.format(folder, error_message))
```

As you have specified in different folder level, you have to call different functions, you may try like below:

```
import os
curr_folder = os.getcwd()
for root, folders, files in os.walk(curr_folder):
    for folder in folders:
        print('dir is: ', folder)
        folder_level = root[len(curr_folder)+1:].count(os.sep)
        print('level is: ', folder_level)
        if folder_level == 0:
            # call myfunction0
            pass
        elif folder_level == 1:
            # call myfunction1
            pass
        elif folder_level == 2:
            # call myfunction2
            pass
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately the example I gave was maybe too simplified. At different subfolder levels I'm using different functions (`myfunction1`, `myfunction2`, etc. like in my ideal code block) so `os.walk` wouldn't work in this case.